# Having trouble connecting QGIS with postgres database with postgis extension

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0, ubuntu

I am working on Ubuntu Precise with postgresql version 9.3 and postgis 2.0.

After initially starting my postgres database and eventually getting permission errors that would prevent postgres from starting due to my modifying the pg_hba.conf file I followed a tutorial from ArchLinux [ArchLinux postgres setup](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PostgreSQL#Installing_PostgreSQL)which stated to create a directory to house my database cluster. Previously I did not do so and had less trouble connecting to QGIS. I know postgres out of the box comes with a default database cluster, so I am wondering if I am attempting to connect to the wrong cluster?

I have config files in two different directories as a result of the tutorial I followed:
*with root user: /etc/postgresql/9.3/main
*under postgres (default auto-created linux user): /var/lib/postgres/data

In any case after making my modifications I also restarted my postgres server and every time I start my server I do so from etc/init.d/postgresql. If so, how exactly do I go about fixing that without breaking my postgres installation?

My error is connection refused, but my port(5432) is listening when I checked with telnet. I am trying to connect with the add Postgis layer GUI option in QGIS Dufour installed on a windows box.

*my pg_hba entry is host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
*local_addresses was set to * in postgresql.conf

When I tried to connect on my database server via its local in the postgres user I tried psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -d postgres

...and I got "could not connect to server, etc", which leads me to believe the loopback is failing because wildcard should allow localhost as well.

Are you supposed to be able to connect to the server on a local machine or...?
Do I have to change my iptables default settings?

*No particular errors on my postgresql installation stuck out.

Comment: Please improve your question, what are the errors.. how are you trying to connect.

Comment: Can you post how you installed PostGIS? Were there any errors during the installation?

Comment: Have you tried to connect to the database locallly from the database server? what is the output when you do
`psql postgres postgres`

Comment: yes I have but it simply gives me the psql prompt.

Comment: that's good, try connecting with qgis to the the same database (postgres) and with the same user. Just for testing put the firewall on the server down and post here the error, if any.

Comment: Trying to connect via QGIS gave me the same error. On my server machine it gave me password authentication failed despite my having set pg_hba to md5.

Comment: just edit the pg_hba.conf file and set connections comming from loopback to trust or .. just use ident authentication. Try to connect again using the postgres user. After you connect locally you can move on to the QGIS connection.

Comment: yeah I tried to edit the pg_hba file and it basically caused my postgresql server to no longer start. The error states it can not open the pg_hba.conf permission denied. MDT fatal, could not load pg_hba. What I think happened is essentially I edited a file that caused weak security, but I'm not entirely sure how to go about fixing that.

Comment: even when I go back and revert my pg_hba file, my permissions for root for the pg_hba file is -rw-r-----

Comment: In the pg_hba.conf try only having:

`# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust

# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust`
All local connections should work,

Comment: Also, you could try to connect via `psql -h localhost ...`, which would use the address-based IP connection instead of the local socket (as far as i understand this).

Answer (score 3):

I think I understand why it isn't working for you, I had this problem some time ago.
Although you installed the database with the postgis extension try the "create extension postgis" before connecting to that database. This is why it gives you an error when it tries to do the "select postgis_version()" function. In conclusion, try and connect to a database that has postgis extension enabled.